# child behind fixed parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a child behind a parent, but this isn't working as I can find on the internet;

I've found the following: http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/a9wQJ/
but that didn't work in my setting, this is my setting simulated:
http://codepen.io/cskiwi/pen/JGovdM

So in my hmtl I'm trying to get the div with id `search-suggestion` to get it behind the `nav-wrapper` (so the shadow is casted on `search-suggestion`)

html:

```
<nav class="blended">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="row hide-on-med-and-down">
      <div class="col l3">
        thing
      </div>
      <div class="col l6">
        <form class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input id="search" type="search">
            <label for="search"><i class="mdi-action-search"></i></label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="search-suggestion" class="dropdown-content hide-on-med-and-down">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="app col s6">
            <h5>Stuff</h5>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">things</a></li>
              <li><a href="">things</a></li>
              <li><a href="">things</a></li>
              <li><a href="">things</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="app col s6">
            <h5>Things</h5>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Stuff</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Stuff</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Stuff</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Stuff</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col l3">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and with the following scss

```
nav  {
  .nav-wrapper{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    .input-field input[type=search] {
      height: 48px;
      line-height: 48px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      padding: 0 10px 0 75px;
      width: 800px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      color: #ff8766;
      z-index: 4;
    }
    &> div {
      z-index:initial;
    }
  }

  #search-suggestion {
    background: red;
    top: 60px;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
      position: absolute;
  }
}

.row  {
  .col.l3{
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
   .col {
      float: left;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0 0.75rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: Hmm, good point :p gimme sec, i'll update, Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't move a child behind a fixed parent. As a work around, I would suggest moving your shadow to the child `.row` element:

```
nav  {
  .nav-wrapper{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;

    >.row {
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      background: #FFF;

      &:after { /* clearfix */
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
      }
    }

    /* ...rest of code ... */
}
```

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGovOB)

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can't put `childs` behind `parents` no matter what you do because the child is `inhereting` from the `parent`, but you can still try to put the `child` at a z-index -1, but it will send the `child` under the body element, and if you try to give z-index to the `parent` and a lower z-index to the `child`, behind it will always give the same z-index to the `child`.

What i recommend you is to **pull out** the *search-suggestion* and play with ***negative margins*** or ***positions***.